# Need to print out error messages for improper input; validation

Tags: python, validation

I'm writing a python script where I find the average of the sum of three numbers. I am using arguments for inputting the numbers. I need to finish the script by printing out error messages.
If I enter something like:

- avg3 3 5
- avg3 3 4 5 6
- avg3 3 one 5

it needs to print an error telling me how to use it.

Here is the start of the script:

```
def main():
    num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
    num3 = int(sys.argv[3])
    avg = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3
    print("The average of " +str(num1) + " " + str(num2) + " " + str(num3) + " " + "is " + str(round(avg,2)))
```

Comment: What errors are you trying to warn the user about? passing args, correct formats?

Comment: Not quite, looking to print out an error message telling the user to enter 3 numbers like "1 2 3". It can't be "1 2 3 4" or "1 2" or "1 two 3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:

For checking forcing an input of 3 numbers, and error checking:

```
def main():
    
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print("You did not enter the correct amount of arguments")
    else:
        try:
            num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
            num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
            num3 = int(sys.argv[3])
            avg = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3

            print(f"The average of {num1} {num2} {num3} is {round(avg, 2)}")

        except (UnboundLocalError, IndexError) as e:
            # When you don't pass any args
            print("You need to pass arguments")
            print(f"($ python avg.py 3 1 2)\n Error = {e}")
        except ValueError as e:
            # You need to use numbers
            print(f"You need to pass arguments as ints")
            print(f"(1 or 432. not 1.2, 324.0)\n Error = {e}")
            print(f"(1 or 432. not 1.2, 324.0)\n Error = {e}")
```

See the below for explanation:

---

`len(sys.argv)` will be `4` when there are 3 arguments (try `print(sys.argv)` for exploring this)

You could use a `try` statement to catch and `except` two common exceptions when passing args:

```
def main():
    try:
        num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
        num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
        num3 = int(sys.argv[3])
        avg = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3

        print(f"The average of {num1} {num2} {num3} is {round(avg, 2)}")

    except (UnboundLocalError, IndexError) as e:
        # When you don't pass any args
        print("You need to pass arguments")
        print(f"($ python avg.py 3 1 2)\n Error = {e}")
    except ValueError as e:
        # You need to use numbers
        print(f"You need to pass arguments as ints")
        print(f"(1 or 432. not 1.2, 324.0)\n Error = {e}")
```

`try` will run a block, and `except` will run when it's listed exceptions are met in the `try` block (exiting the `try` loop).

---

You could also simplify your code to:

```
nums = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:4]]
avg = sum(nums)/3
```

And access your numbers with

```
# Same as nums1
nums[0]
```

and change the length of incoming arguments to anything `>= 1` (if you want):

```
def main():
    try:

        nums = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)]]
        avg = sum(nums)/len(nums)

        print(f"The average of {', '.join([str(x) for x in nums])} is {round(avg, 2)}")

    except (UnboundLocalError, IndexError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
        # When you don't pass any args
        print("You need to pass arguments")
        print(f"($ python avg.py 3 1 2)\n Error = {e}")
    except ValueError as e:
        # You need to use numbers
        print(f"You need to pass arguments as ints")
        print(f"(1 or 432. not 1.2, 324.0)\n Error = {e}")
```

Comment: I just attempted using the try statement and when I try to enter my arguments, I do not get a response, whether the input was correct or incorrect

Comment: I made corrections and it now prints out errors when I enter "1 4" or "1" or "one 4 5". I need to be able to print out an error though when someone types in more than three integers such as "1 4 5 6".

Comment: @Kusanagi97, edited try the top block. And what are you typing in terminal?

Comment: Thank you for continuing to reach out Freddy. I would be typing into the terminal "avg3 1 4 5 6" and receive an error for typing in too many arguments

Comment: I made the correction for the length of the arguments and all scenarios now print out an error. Thank you very much for your time and teaching:)

Comment: No worries @Kusanagi97, do you have any more questions?

Comment: No more questions from me, thanks again @Freddy Mcloughlan

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about catching the `one` arg as an error, you could simply catch a `value` error.

```
def main():
    try:
        num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
        num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
        num3 = int(sys.argv[3])
        avg = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3
        print("The average of " +str(num1) + " " + str(num2) + " " + str(num3) + " " + "is " + str(round(avg,2)))
    except ValueError:
        print("All your values need to be ints")
```

This will ensure that anything outside of a number being passed in as an arg would result in the message `All your values need to be ints`.

This won't catch any other errors, so you will have to catch them separately. For instance, your first example where you only pass 2 values won't work since there is no `num3`, but I'm assuming that isn't what you are asking about here.